# Primefaces exception INFO: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, exception, jsf-2, primefaces, lazy-loading

I have implemented LazyLoading for datatable. When I run through datatable by using pagination I am getting the following exceptions.

```
com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFO: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.setRowIndex(LazyDataModel.java:62)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:411)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:403)
```

ManagedBean

```
@PostConstruct
    public LazyDataModel<Request> getLazyModel() {
          if (lazyModel == null) {
           lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<Request>() {

            @Override
            public List<Request> load(int startingAt, int maxPerPage, String sortField,
                       SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
             return getRequestService().getRequest(startingAt, maxPerPage, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
            }
           };
           lazyModel.setRowCount(getRequestService().getRequestCount());           

          }
          return lazyModel;
         }
```

JSF

```
<h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="req" lazy="true" value="#{reqMB.lazyModel}"
            paginator="true" rows="10"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
```

DAO for getting row count.

```
int count = ((Long)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery
("select count(*) from Request").uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

**Update 1**

```
com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFO: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.setRowIndex(LazyDataModel.java:62)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowModel(UIData.java:411)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:403)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processChildren(UIData.java:291)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processPhase(UIData.java:263)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:641)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1601)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: Have you by any chance zero in `maxPerPage`?

Comment: @AlexZam `maxPerPage` is always 5 or 10 when I test which is by default in datatable drop down. I never changed.

Comment: This problem suggests that `rows="0"` in your `<p:dataTable>`. Are you running the code you think you're running? Perhaps you've a `rows="#{bean.rows}"` which returned `0` on postback?

Comment: @BalusC  I have set `rows="10"` and this is hard coded, not dynamic. Dynamic value I am setting is `lazyModel.setRowCount(getRequestService().getRequestCount());` What is the best way to debug this?

Comment: Put a "modification" breakpoint on `pageSize` property of `LazyDataModel` (or just an "access" breakpoint on the `setPageSize()` method wherein you check if it's ever called with `0` as value). At the moment when the value of `0` is attempted to be set, check the stacktrace for the who and the why.

Comment: @BalusC lazyModel.getPageSize(); returns zero, not sure how this happens because I am not setting any values for pageSize. Complete stackraace I have added in my question as update 1.

Comment: The page size is set with value of `rows` attribute. Again, debug the `setPageSize()` method and look at the call stack who set it and with which value. I did not tell to debug the `getPageSize()`. Normally, the `DataTable#loadLazyData()` should call it with value of `DataTable#getRows()` which in turn should return `10` in your particular code.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry for my ignorance, how can I debug setPageSize() because I do not have java code, I have only class file for that?

Comment: Just include PrimeFaces source code? You can download it from their homepage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to comment [#23 in the issue tracker of primefaces](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1544#c23) the following should fix that problem

```
@Override
public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
    /*
     * The following is in ancestor (LazyDataModel):
     * this.rowIndex = rowIndex == -1 ? rowIndex : (rowIndex % pageSize);
     */
    if (rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0) {
        super.setRowIndex(-1);
    }
    else
        super.setRowIndex(rowIndex % getPageSize());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  have noticed that when scope is view then this problem doesn't seems to appear.